# Check if word appears twice in webpage with python

Tags: python

I'm logging into a site and then searching the site. From the results I'm searching through the html and seeing if I get a match. It all works perfectly except for the fact that the site says "Search results for xyz" which is picked up by my search so I always get a positive result when it could be negative. My current code

```
... Previous code to log in etc...

words = ['xyz']

br.open ('http://www.example.com/browse.php?psec=2&search=%s' % words)
html = br.response().read()

for word in words:
   if word in html:
      print "%s found." % word
   else:
      print "%s not found." % word
```

As a solution I would like to check if the word appears twice or more and if so then it is positive. If it appears only once then it is obviously just the "Search results for xyz" that is being picked up so it is not found. How would I go about adapting my current code to check for two occurrences and not just one?

Thanks

Comment: As an other solution, maybe you can use BeautifulSoup to choose in which website's part (a particular <div>, for example) to do the word search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this,

```
for word in words:
    if html.count(word)>1:
        #your logic goes here
```

Example

```
>>> words =['the.cat.and.hat']
>>> html = 'the.cat.and.hat'
>>> for w in words:
...       if html.count(w)>1:
...           print 'more than one match'
...       elif html.count(w) == 1:
...           print 'only one match found'
...       else:
...           print 'no match found'
...
only one match found
>>>
```

Comment: Does .count count individual words or whole string. So for example if words ='the.cat.and.hat' and html='the.cat.and.hat and cat' would it match twice because it finds cat twice or just once because it only find the.cat.and.hat once?

Comment: `if words =['the.cat.and.hat']` and i do `html.count(words[0])` the output is `0`.

Comment: So if you pass a string to it, it counts `individual words` and if the case is list of strings see my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks. So if words =['the.cat.and.hat'] how do I get it to only match the entire sentence 'the.cat.and.hat'? Could you modify you answer please?

Comment: Seems like the source code has more instances than the visual site which was messing with results. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

In short you want the count of occurrences of a particular word in a string. Use string.count(). See [This](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.count).